# Filtering through models where value is not full

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a table which filled with data from db. Now I'm creating search form. Which search everything I want but only if I give it exactly the string which match value in db. For example I type review in search and it will search:

```
qs = Model.objects.filter(status=review)
```

Then I return data with response and my Vue page rendering it as i want.
My is choice field, review, registering, cancelled etc. But user can see them as Reviewing, Registering etc. So they not match and user will type Reviewing, which will return empty qs. Also I want to search to find result after user types 'viewi'. Is there a way to do it through django server side, because I couldn't find information in documentation

Comment: "review" is variable? What is the field type of "status"? Please show me Django model definition.

Comment: well, review is one of a choices for status. But in view i use variable that im getting from request. I posted an answer already. Sorry, didn't find it in documentation from first look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand your question completely, I guess what you should be looking at is Q() of Django using which you can do complex database queries with query set.

check this page. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q

A simple example goes like this:
what you want is:

```
select * from Model where status like '%view%
```

which returns all rows with reviewing or viewing or review as status value.

Using Q() you can do same like

```
Model.objects.get(status__icontains='view')
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a soluction. You need to add __icontains to the end of ur field in your filter. In my case it will look like:

```
qs = Model.objects.filter(status__icontains=query)
```

It will be sql code

```
WHERE status ILIKE %query%
```